# Upload CSV in different encoding than UTF-8

Tags: csv, upload, import, data-import-wizard

Is it possible to set an encoding for a file that is uploaded via a VisualForce page? I am getting errors stating that the content of the uploaded file is not UTF-8 encoded. Ideally, the user would be able to specify the file encoding himself, similar to the [Account and Contact import wizard](http://na13.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/import_my_organizations_accounts_and_contacts.htm).

Comment: You want to upload your files in static resource ?? Please provide more information !!

Comment: I just want to post a CSV file via a form and process its contents, not saving it in salesforce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your CSV file is being processed by a VF controller as part of a binding from the `apex:inputFile` component to a controller variable of type Blob, then, if you want to manipulate the CSV contents in the controller, the Blob must be converted to a String using Blob instance method `myBlob.toString()`.

This `toString()` method requires that the Blob contain only UTF-8 characters as all Apex string operations are done in UTF-8.

Conclusion, the uploaded file when presented to the VF page has to be in UTF-8 before the page action executes.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question. Our "fix" is to extend our documentation so that users know how to produce valid UTF-8 documents. Salesforce drives me crazy sometimes…

Comment: Be sure to let your users know that MSFT Excel will not save CSV files in UTF-8 unless they start in UTF-8.  You need to use Google docs, Open Office, or convert the file using Notepad or other text editor. If all the chars are ASCII A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and common punctuation, then ASCII = UTF-8