# Fahrenheit symbol (°F) causing "BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string" exception

Tags: csv, blob

The requirement I'm working on requires to read a CSV file with temperature measurements. But Fahrenheit or Celcius symbols are causing exceptions when converting csv blob file to string using toString(). I ran into this issue many time in the past but it's because of mysterious special characters that get inserted because of copy-paste. This time i inserted these symbols from excel insert tool box, it didn't work. I queried some data points with these symbols in my salesforce org and pasted in csv. It didn't work either. Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `EcnodingUtil.base64Encode` ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm#apex_System_EncodingUtil_base64Encode))?

Comment: once you save your CSV file on your local machine, open it in a text editor that can display hex and verify that the degree sign you  are using is a valid UTF-8 character. The degree symbol should be UTF-8 `00B0` = ASCII `B0`.  MSFT Excel won't save CSV as UTF-8 but this typically is a problem only with asian languages or eastern european character sets when it comes to SFDC

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes. I tried that. It didn't help. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @crop1645 I have opened the csv in notepad++ and encoded the whole text to UTF-8 and it works. The funny thing is I encoded it to UTF-8 many times this morning, but forgot save it and thought it is not making any difference. As you mentioned text editor, I thought of giving it another try and it works. Thanks.

Comment: this has made me more curious - how ae the CSV fles coming into apex? Via VF upload, REST/SOAP API, inbound email handler?

Comment: Through VF page.

Comment: @crop1645 My question is unrelated to the thread. I thought using rest we can receive information in either json or xml. But from your earlier comment, I learnt that csv can be received through REST. Can you please give me sample apex code to parse inbound csv(from REST) if you have? Thanks.

Comment: @crop1645 The unicode scalar value for the degree sign is `U+00B0`. If you are looking at the hex values of the file, you will only see `00B0` if the file is encoded as UTF-16BE. UTF-8 would encode this character as `C2B0`, and it actually isn't in ASCII; it's ISO-8859-1 that encodes it at `0B`.

Comment: @martin - my comment/answer thread was a bit muddled as I realized afterwards that the OP was not about the degree sign but about a different unicode character for the combined degree+F or degree+C character. Nevertheless your comment is helpful

Answer (score 2):

Somehow, your users are inserting into their source spreadsheet a character that the spreadsheet can't encode as a valid UTF-8 character upon SAVE. SFDC only accepts UTF-8 characters. ASCII 00-FF maps to UTF-8 asis and the degree symbol `°` is ASCII `B0`. So you would expect to be fine.

But, if the user is copy-pasting the combined degree+C symbol `℃`  (UTF-8 = `U+2103`) into Excel and then saving as CSV, that is not in ASCII 00-FF and won't save as UTF-8 by Excel. Same issue with `℉` which is UTF-8 `U+2109`

*Who knew there were such UTF-8 characters? Cool.*

MSFT Excel (through 2013, last version I have checked) will not save CSV files as UTF-8. [Stackexchange discussion on VF uploads of CSV files here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/24125/2602).

Example:  `℉` does not save as `e2 84 89` but instead saves as `3f` = `?`

Open Office does have a save as CSV with UTF-8 encoding but your org may not use Open Office.

Google Docs does have a save as CSV with UTF-8 encoding but your org may not use Google Docs and anyway, as a cloud solution, having to save the file in Google Docs to your desktop and then upload to SFDC is a user bummer.

Comment: Re encoding the file in notepad++ has a side effect. Even though we are looking at a csv, when we re encode, it is actually changing the format to unicode text. When I duplicate the csv, both the original and copy are changed to unicode text. I even pasted UTF-8 encoded text in the individual cells, but still getting the blob error. I don't understand why it would throw blob exception when the text was encoded into UTF-8 and pasted into the cells. Will the text loose its properties when I paste it in csv? How can I import ℉ now?

Comment: If using MSFT Excel,  "save as CSV" will never save chars pasted in as UTF-8 as UTF-8.

Comment: I'm not saving xlsx file as csv. I open a csv and paste the UTF-8 encoded text into the cells. Even that is not working..

Comment: as I said, MSFT Excel will never, ever save UTF-8 encoded chars in a .csv extension